# How can I add bootstrap's datepicker to web site?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am developing angularjs Application.

This is the code :

```
<directive date="date" date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" >
    <input ng-model="Date" type="text"/>               
</directive>
```

How can I add angular directive using bootstrap?

I am thinking to use bootstrap or what ever datepicker for bind input.
If not clear, comment.

Comment: There are numerous datepicker directives readily available and easily found in a web search. Have you tried any?

Answer (score 1):

use datepicker form angular-ui [page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), you have easy to understand examples there.

Comment: Thanks your idea. It's very useful solution.

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems or doubts, but I think everything it's straight forward :)